# How to set Controller-wide global variables

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Currently I use `@ModelAttribute` to set global variables (e.g. tweets for the footer) in my `@Controller`:

```
public @Controller class MainController {
    public @ModelAttribute void global(ModelMap map) {
        map.addAttribute("tweets", /*...*/null);
    }
}
```

But they're logically gone when creating another Controller to keep things clean and separated:

```
public @Controller class GalleryController {
    // ...
}
```

What's the best practice to set global variables Controller wide?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to put some data to every page it is easy to use interceptor:

```
public class PagePopulationInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
        if(modelAndView != null) {
            User user = userService.findOne(request);
            modelAndView.addObject("myUserProfile", user);
        }
    }

}
```

To make this work also declare interceptor in webmvc-config.xml (spring configuration for webapp):

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <mvc:interceptor>
        <mvc:mapping path="/**"/>
        <bean class="com.yourcompany.yourapp.util.PagePopulationInterceptor" />
    </mvc:interceptor>
    <!-- other interceptors (locale, theme and so on) -->
</mvc:interceptors>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can extend HandlerInterceptorAdapter and add common modelAttributes thr