# Global variable using interceptor spring mvc 4

Tags: spring-mvc, interceptor

I have many pages, where i want to use a single property value of type String.

Fro example, i have login page, after i login i will set a property, whether it is admin or not, according to this property value, i will do some action on other jsp pages as well. To do this below url is giving some solution, but i don't know how can i use this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18211075/how-to-set-controller-wide-global-variables

I want to read this property value and use this in all different jsp pages.

Iadded the following class

```
public class PagePopulationInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

        @Autowired
        private UserService userService;

        @Override
        public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
            if(modelAndView != null) {
                userService.setUserType("admin");
                modelAndView.addObject("myUserProfile", userService);
            }
        }
    }
```

and as well changed spring-servlet xml

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <mvc:interceptor>
        <mvc:mapping path="/**"/>
        <beans:bean class="com.test.PagePopulationInterceptor" />
    </mvc:interceptor>
    <!-- other interceptors (locale, theme and so on) -->
</mvc:interceptors>
```

In JSP how i tried calling is

```
<div>

<p>${myUserProfile.userType}</p>

</div>
```

In the above jsp code, i did not receive any values.

Comment: Are you sure you wanna do this way? Even when it gets to work, as UserService is a instance variable of the interceptor, after one admin user logs in, every other users (already logged in or which logs in after) will have "admin" as userType. Are you sure you are looking forward to achieve this?

Comment: What about adding the varible to the session ?

Comment: Done this adding session variable concept.